# How to handle exceptions inside an entity in symfony2 framework

Tags: symfony, exception, doctrine-orm, try-catch, entity

I want to get some data from an entity class. I tried to use try/catch to handle problems but it is not working (still gives me the Exception screen).

> Error: Call to a member function getGroup() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/html/system/src/Project/SomeBundle/Entity/MyEntity.php line
>   139
>   500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException Stack Trace

How can I do something like that in an entity?

Code/Entity:

```
<?php
namespace Project\SomeBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * MyEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_entity")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Project\SomeBundle\Entity\Repository\MyEntityRepository")
 */
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(max="255")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var Item[]|Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Project\SomeBundle\Entity\Item", mappedBy="itemType", cascade={"remove"}, fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
     */
    protected $items;

    // [...]


    /**
     * Get some data
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSomeData()
    {
        $result = null;
        try {
            $result = $this->getName() . ' - ' . $this->getItems()->last()->getGroup()->getCode();
        }
        catch(\Exception $exception) {
            $result = $this->getName();

            $logFile = fopen('/tmp/error.log', 'a');
            fwrite($logFile, $exception->getMessage());
            fclose($logFile);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You don't do that in entity. Wherever you call `getSomeData()` eg. in a service, factory etc. catch it there.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Error: Call to a member function getGroup() on a non-object in...` has very little to do with *where* you're receiving it. It means that you are trying to call a function on something that isn't an object.

It seems likely that `$this->getItems()->last()` is somehow returning `null` (because there are no items), and then you're calling `getGroup()` on `null` which is a non-object.

Try to debug the object on which you're calling `getGroup()` and see what value it holds just before you call it.

Comment: Thanks.
The error comes from:
[...]->last()->getGroup()->getCode();

...and yeah, the reason is that "last()" returns "false" so "getGroup()" fails.

My problem is that why the program doesn't catch the Exception within try/catch?

Comment: Ah sorry. Yes, that's weird. Could you try explicitly catching `FatalErrorException` instead of `\Exception`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch that error you must write try catch as following

```
    try {
        $result = $this->getName() . ' - ' . $this->getItems()->last()->getGroup()->getCode();
    }
    catch(\Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException $exception) {
        $result = $this->getName();

        $logFile = fopen('/tmp/error.log', 'a');
        fwrite($logFile, $exception->getMessage());
        fclose($logFile);
    }
```

You can see I have changed **\Exception** to **\Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException** in above code block

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, since FatalErrorException extends \Exception.

Comment: @Denes, you must confirm class of $exception object

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. Some say FatalErrorException is not catchable.

Comment: PHP7 makes it a bit easier to catch these sort of things.

Comment: Thank you guys but I eventually gave it up and rewrote my code entirely.